# Recieve "Insufficient scope" error even though i have sufficient one

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

Implementing authentication via JWT token, using OAuth2ResourceServer (Spring 3)

## **spring security config**:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final RsaProperties rsaKeys;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager() {
        var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(authenticationService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeys.publicKey()).privateKey(rsaKeys.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenService tokenService() {
        return new JwtTokenService(jwtEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/authentication/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/credit/request").hasAuthority("SCOPE_usr")
                .and()
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer :: jwt )
                .build();
    }
}
```

## **JwtTokenService**:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenService {
    private final JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;

    public String generateAccessToken(UserDetailsEntity userDetails) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                .subject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();
        return this.jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }

    public String generateRefreshToken(UserDetailsEntity userDetails) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(10, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                .subject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();
        return this.jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }

    public String parseToken(String token) {
        try {
            SignedJWT decodedJwt = SignedJWT.parse(token);
            return decodedJwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So my tokens contains claim "scope" with value "SCOPE_usr" which required on "/credit/request" endpoint, even though server continues to response with 403 code error and "insufficient scope" message. I tried to hardcode scope to "SCOPE_usr" in JwtTokenService, so all my tokens pass the endpoint check (I understand, that it may sound stupid, but at this moment that's the way I think OAuth2 server works). Can somebody explain, which way OAuth2ResourceServer checks scopes, and what should I try to fix that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the default authorities converter which takes scope claim entries and adds `SCOPE_` prefix to it. With this converter and the `requestMatchers` access rules you have in your conf, the scope in the token should be `usr` (which will be converted to `SCOPE_usr` authority).